# replacement the phrase in the string according to the dictionary

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dictionary, replace

welcome

please tell me how to best solve the following problem:
I have a string containing the text with some phrases, located between the delimiters "$$" and "$$"

```
var string = "..$$xxx$$..$$yyy$$..$$xxx$$.."
```

is an associative array - Translation Dictionary

```
var dictionary = [];
dictionary [ 'xxx'] = 'yyy';
dictionary [ 'aaa'] = 'bb cc';
```

etc.

**it is necessary to replace the phrase in the string according to the dictionary.**

the only thing that comes to mind is:

1. using regular expressions searching for any phrase (
2. looking in the dictionary translation
3. using regular expressions replace the
   phrase
4. 1-3 repeat until there are no more phrases which must be
   replaced by

All right? Or you can do as a faster and easier?

Comment: you can use the 'split()' function and store the individual phrases in an array. Then you can traverse the array and just map the phrases. Finally you can join the array elements using the delimiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach you may try :

```
var source = "..$$xxx$$..$$yyy$$..$$xxx$$..";
var phrases = source.split('$$');
var transformedPhrases = phrases.map(function(phrase){ 
                             return dictionary[phrase] || phrase; 
                         });
var transformedSource = transformedPhrases.join('$$');
```

Comment: khm, wittily!

**Aqua ferro levior est**

Big Thanks